# Scala Variance Concept, why it doesn't compile

Tags: scala, concept

I am a noob to Scala so please don't negative vote.

```
class MyClass extends AnyRef
class MySubClass extends MyClass

val af0: (Seq[_]) => Boolean = (s) ⇒ { s eq null }

val f4: (MySubClass) => Boolean = (s) => { s eq null }

val af2: (List[_]) => Boolean = af0 //(Line 1)
val f7: MyClass => Boolean = f4 //(Line 2)
```

Why line (1) compiles and line (2) does not? To me they both are same as Sequence is subtype of List. How to make it work? like in case of Line 1?

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/collections.html [List object hierarchy]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala Co and Contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36459965/scala-co-and-contravariance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is called [contravariance](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html). Function parameters need to be contravariant because of this:

```
class HisSubClass extends MyClass

val his = new HisSubClass 
f7(his) // his is accepted as MyClass
```

Now `f4` would be called with something which is not `MySubClass`, which would be error.

The case of `Seq` / `List` works because it is the other way around. `List` is subclass of `Seq`.

```
val af2: (List[_]) => Boolean = af0
```

is like

```
val aff0: (MyClass) => Boolean = (s) ⇒ { s eq null }
val aff2: (MySubClass) => Boolean = aff0
```

#### Promise (contract)

What helped me a lot to understand the parameter / return value variance was to think about type declarations as promises (or contracts). Return value is covariant, because you have promised your return value will be of type `MyClass`, and by providing `MySubClass` in a subclass you are still keeping your promise. Promising you will accept the parameter of the type `MyClass` and then trying to declare a subclass member accepting only `MySubClass` means trying to narrow down the promise, which you cannot (subclass must fully implement the parent class).

With your example in `f4` you have promised the function will be given `MySubClass` as a parameter. When you try to assign this to `f7` you are trying to break this promise, as you could pass any `MyClass` to `f4` by calling it via `f7`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you try to assign to value of type `Function1[MyClass, Boolean]` value of type `Function1[MyClass, Boolean]`, but first type parameter of `Function1` is contravariant, see [API doc](http://trait%20Function1[-T1,%20+R]%20extends%20AnyRef):

`trait Function1[-T1, +R] extends AnyRef`

But it allows you do this:

```
val f7: MyClass => Boolean = s => s eq null 
val f44: (MySubClass) => Boolean = f7
```

You can find the explanation of variances [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html).

Comment: then why Line (2) according to question compiles?

Comment: Because `Seq` is a supertype of `List`, not a subtype. If you swap `Seq` and `List` in your example, then it'll be the equivalent of what you're doing with `MyClass` and that line won't compile either.