# Scala covariance, contravariance confusion

Tags: scala, covariance, contravariance

I am a newcomer to Scala and it's really very confusion. Please help me.

```
/**
2    * Remember! In Scala, every function that takes one argument 
3    * is an instance of Function1 with signature:
4    *
5    * trait Function1[-T, +S] extends AnyRef
6    */
7   
8   class Vehicle(val owner: String)
9   class Car(owner: String) extends Vehicle(owner)
10  
11  object Printer {
12
13    val cars = List(new Car("john"), new Car("paul"))
14
15    def printCarInfo(getCarInfo: Car => AnyRef) {
16      for (car <- cars) println(getCarInfo(car))
17    }
18  }
19  
20  object Customer extends App {
21
22   val getOwnerInfo: (Vehicle => String) = _.owner
23   
24   Printer.printCarInfo(getOwnerInfo)
25  }
```

This code is taken from https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/variance-in-java-and-scala-63af925d21dc

**The Rule is:**

> This rule of function being covariant in its input type and
>   contravariant in its return type comes from the Liskov substitution
>   principle (LSP). It says that T is a subtype of U if it supports the
>   same operations as U and all of its operations require less (or same)
>   and provide more (or same) than the corresponding operations in U
>   (subtyping is reflexive so S <: S).

**So my question is if I can pass a subtype where a super type is required (above code line number 15 and 22) then why the following code does not works?**

```
class MyClass extends AnyRef
class MySubClass extends MyClass

abstract class Class {
  val f1: (Any) => Any = ???
  val f2: (Any) => Boolean = ???
  val f3: (MyClass) => Any = ???
  val f4: (MySubClass) => Boolean = ???
  val f5: (Any) => Nothing = ???
  val f6: (MyClass) => Null = ???

  val f: (MyClass) => Boolean = f4; //Error
}
```

**Update**
So actually it's like passing a param to the function so I have param can be contravariant [-T] and return can be covariant [+S]

```
    class MyClass extends AnyRef
    class MySubClass extends MyClass

    abstract class Class {
      val f1: (Any) => Any = ???
      val f2: (MyClass) => Boolean = ???
      val f3: (MyClass) => Any = ???
      val f4: (MySubClass) => Boolean = ???
      val f5: (Any) => Nothing = ???
      val f6: (MyClass) => Null = ???

      val f: (MySubClass) => AnyVal = f2
}
```

This is a valid code as `MyClass` is like going Up in the hierarchy and `Boolean` is like cuming down in the hierarchy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala Variance Concept, why it doesn't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51190131/scala-variance-concept-why-it-doesnt-compile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets looks into `printCarInfo` parameter. It's little function that accept `Car` as an argument and returns `AnyRef`: `getCarInfo: Car => AnyRef`.

In scala such functions with one argument can be represented using `trait Function1[-T, +S] extends AnyRef`

`Function1` parametrised by `-T` and `+S` two types. First type represent argument of function. `Car` in our case. And it's contra-variant (minus sign), which means you can pass any `super-type`. `+S` represents return type and it's covariant (plus sign), which means you can pass any sub-type.

`printCarInfo` invoked and parameter of type `Vehicle => String` passed. 
Vehicle is super type for Car and String is subtype for AnyRef, so it satisfy criteria.

So why arguments are in contra variant position and return type in covariant. Let's try to assume opposite for arguments:

`printCarInfo` accept function of type: `Vehicle=>AnyRef` and `getOwnerInfo` is `Car=>AnyRef`

When you trying to implement printCarInfo we can process any argument, not just cars, but lorries and bicycles.
Obviously invocation of `Printer.printCarInfo(getOwnerInfo)` fails as you're trying to getOwnerInfo from lorry or bicycle, while your method implementation can deal with cars only.
Hopefully it's clear.

So regarding your code. It's opposite: you can assign `f4: MysSubClass => Boolean = f` and it will work.

Comment: I understood all except "So regarding your code. It's opposite: you can assign f4: MysSubClass => Boolean = f and it will work." please explain how it is inverse?

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't compile because otherwise e.g. if you had a

```
class MyOtherSubClass extends MyClass
```

your

```
val f: (MyClass) => Boolean
```

could accept a `MyOtherSubClass` as a parameter e.g. `f(new MyOtherSubClass())`, but that would be calling `f4(new MyOtherSubClass())`. But `MyOtherSubClass` isn't a `MySubClass`, so you'd be calling `f4` with the wrong type